# PHP class method with closure CURL headers

Tags: php, curl, closures

I have the class below, in order to analyze a URL

```
<?php
class URLFetcher {
    private $ch;
    private $url = '';

    public function __construct(string $url) {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function fetch(): URLFetcher {
        $headers = [];
        $this->ch = curl_init($this->url);
        curl_setopt_array($this->ch, [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0',
            CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function($curl, $header) use (&$headers) {
                var_dump($header);
                $header2 = trim($header);
                if($header2 !== '') $headers[] = $header2;
                return strlen($header);
            }
        ]);
        exit(var_dump($headers));
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

I use var_dump in the closure in order to see the headers, as they come from CURL, and at the end, I use var_dump again in order to see all headers.

The problem is that there are no headers printed in the function and at the end, the $headers is printing the empty array.

If I do this without the class, everything works correctly. My question is what am I missing and the code does not work? I hypothesize that it has to do with the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot `curl_exec($this->ch);` at the end of the method.

```
public function fetch(): URLFetcher {
    $headers = [];
    $this->ch = curl_init($this->url);
    curl_setopt_array($this->ch, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0',
        CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function($curl, $header) use (&$headers) {
            $header2 = trim($header);
            if($header2 !== '') $headers[] = $header2;
            return strlen($header);
        }
    ]);

    curl_exec($this->ch);

    exit(var_dump($headers));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Oh mon dieu!!! Damn copy paste. I feel a little embarassed, suppose I should :) Thanks anyway